# IOS EORRO module 'xxx' has a minimum deployment target of iOS "15.0"

Tags: ios

When I created my project，in "General"->"Deployment Info" I chose iOS 15. But now I need to set the version to iOS 14. I changed it to iOS 14 in "Deployment Info" but when I run I get the error:

> Command MergeSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code
> :0: error: compiling for iOS 14.0, but module 'project' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 15.0:

[image: screenshot of error]

I looked through some related questions but they mentioned pods and I didn't introduce any third party packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, the following worked for me:

Click on the project in the Xcode project navigator (first item in list).

Now, in the project settings window that results, select your project, select "Info" and check what the "Deployment Target" is.

Next, select each of your targets, "Build Settings", "Basic", under "Deployment" check the "iOS deployment target". **This may not match that above**, so revise to match.

I hope this fixes your issue!

Comment: I have a similar error running a build from console with `xcodebuild ...`. How could I fix it? I do not see any option to set de "deployment target". I'm using this command `xcodebuild -project BokenEngine.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator15.5 -destination "OS=15.5"`.

Answer (score 13):

In general, I find that issues of this kind are solved by choosing Product > Clean Build Folder. It's probably a (minor) bug in Xcode 13.